# Parallel bit deposit / parallel bit extract on intel compiler/LLVM?

Tags: gcc, clang, intrinsics, icc, bmi

For CPUs that come with [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2_(Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_2)) instructions, one can use parallel bit deposit (pdep) and parallel bit extract (pext) with GCC using the [builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html) :

- `unsigned int _pdep_u32 (unsigned int, unsigned int)`
- `unsigned int _pext_u32 (unsigned int, unsigned int)`
- `unsigned long long _pdep_u64 (unsigned long long, unsigned long long)`
- `unsigned long long _pext_u64 (unsigned long long, unsigned long long)`

What are their equivalent on the Intel compiler ? And on clang ?

Comment: You have an answer. You should accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27371072/506073

Comment: Those *are* the Intel intrinsics, as documented by Intel.  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/.  Most compilers implement most of what Intel documents, including GCC and clang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both, [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-pext-u32-64) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/bmi2intrin_8h_source.html) provide the very same intrinsics.