# Are there bit (un)packing instructions in common x86_64 processor line mmx command for bytes?

Tags: x86, aes, instruction-set, des, bit-packing

dead hachers!
**Background:**
Maybe you know mmx packing/unpacking instruction set, what howewer works on bytes and larger volumes, like shorts, words, etc.

**Quesion:**
Are there any instructions for any  x86_64  processor, to do the similar packing/unpacking but only for bits?

**Purpose:**
It is an idea for optimizing the DES/AES bit shifts, but if you have other proposals about it, you may answer as well.

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you would want those instructions to do?  I'm not clear which MMX packing instructions you have in mind; there's [`PACKSSWB`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packsswb:packssdw) and the like, but I'm not sure what that would mean in terms of bits.

Comment: iin the result, the bits are shifted as they are shifted in the packssXX operation, but in smaller scale inside a byte of 2 byte value .ignoring sign saturation feature, what is not related for bits. 
Furher, it is for 2-x or 4-x blocks. Basically, it is the packing/unpacking for ranges, smaller then a byte

Comment: I still don't quite understand, and I think some examples would help.  But in any case, are you aware of [`PDEP`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) / [`PEXT`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) ?

Comment: yes, great! Thanks, i m looking for something like that! I m not aware of all instructions- i am ASKING for that here. Also if there are any similar, please answer. You can write it as an answer, i ll mark it correct.

Comment: [What's a fast way to space-out bits within a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47692902) includes `pdep`.  Seems like a viable duplicate.  Also I guess [Parallel bit deposit / parallel bit extract on intel compiler/LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27363906)